# LTSupportAutomotive: Selector name found in current argument registers: delegate Exception Type: SIGSEGV Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xac7c95df0

Tags: objective-c, obd-ii

i write 99% in Swift and don´t understand why this Thread is crashing. I cant reproduce it, but it happens sometimes.

The Library is: LTSupportAutomotive
https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive

The error: (got it from HockeyApp Crash Reporter) 
Selector name found in current argument registers delegate

Exception Type: SIGSEGV

Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xac7c95df0

```
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001fe175430 objc_retain + 16
1   LTSupportAutomotive                  0x00000001065816f8 -[LTBTLEReadCharacteristicStream characteristicDidUpdateValue] (LTBTLEReadCharacteristicStream.m:43)
2   LTSupportAutomotive                  0x0000000106582ac8 -[LTBTLESerialTransporter peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] (LTBTLESerialTransporter.m:299)
3   CoreBluetooth                        0x0000000204b42cc0 -[CBPeripheral handleAttributeEvent:args:attributeSelector:delegateSelector:delegateFlag:] + 236
4   CoreBluetooth                        0x0000000204b42e20 -[CBPeripheral handleCharacteristicEvent:characteristicSelector:delegateSelector:delegateFlag:] + 128
5   CoreBluetooth                        0x0000000204b3e4d0 -[CBPeripheral handleMsg:args:] + 352
6   CoreBluetooth                        0x0000000204b38bdc -[CBCentralManager handleMsg:args:] + 200
7   CoreBluetooth                        0x0000000204b47750 __30-[CBXpcConnection _handleMsg:]_block_invoke + 56
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe9c56c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe9c6484 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe96dbd0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 588
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe96e74c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 480
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe96da9c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe96e718 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001fe976eb8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001feba90dc _pthread_wqthread + 308
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001febabcec start_wqthread + 0
```

The crashing Code in

```
-(void)characteristicDidUpdateValue
{
    NSData* value = _characteristic.value;
    [_buffer appendData:value];
    [self.delegate stream:self handleEvent:NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable]; <--- here it is crashing
}
```

here it starts from:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
#ifdef DEBUG_THIS_FILE
    NSString* debugString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* replacedWhitespace = [[debugString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r"];
    XLOG( @"%@ >>> %@", peripheral, replacedWhitespace );
#endif

    if ( error )
    {
        LOG( @"Could not update value for characteristic %@: %@", characteristic, error );
        return;
    }

    [_inputStream characteristicDidUpdateValue]; <---
}
```

can someone help me with Objective-C to avoid this crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the delegate was unsafe_unretained, instead of weak.